# File signature detection tool

Tags: windows, gratis, data-analysis, file-format

Is there a PE (portable executable) signature detection tool which allows commercial use?
Here's what I tried so far:

- [Exeinfo PE](http://exeinfo.atwebpages.com/) is free for non-commercial use. No information available regarding commerial use.
- [PEiD](http://www.aldeid.com/wiki/PEiD) official website no longer maintained. No license information in readme.txt.
- [Detect it easy](http://ntinfo.biz/index.php/detect-it-easy) has no license information.

Requirements:

- Windows (at least 7 x64)
- Gratis
- commercial use allowed
- no license guessing, please. It should be a clear statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am the author of [Detect It Easy](https://github.com/horsicq/Detect-It-Easy) (DIE).

- It is cross platform (Windows, OS and Linux).
- Free
- Commercial use is fine. Anybody can use DIE free and without any restrictions whether the usage is commercial or not.

If you need more information: horsicq[at]gmail.com

Comment: That's wonderful. And since you have also written me an email, this is quite credible. If you could just put that statement onto your website near to DIE, it might also help others who respect licenses. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add some more information about how your software fulfills each requirement in the question?

Comment: 1) Windows(32 and 64), Linux(32 and 64), Mac OS.
2) Absolute free.

Comment: 3) Commercial use allowed.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [Stud_PE](http://www.cgsoftlabs.ro/studpe.html) which has a signature scanner included:

[image: Screenshot of Stud_PE]

It fulfills all my requirements:

- runs on Windows
- it's freeware
- commercial use: I have contacted the author by email and he responded on 2014-07-15 20:36:

  > yes, you can do whatever you want with it as slog as you keep it free.
  >
  > > Hi Christi,
  > >     is Stud_PE also free for commercial use?